# R: Access the last subelement of each element in a list

Tags: r, list, split, element, apply

Say I have a character vector like:

```
 x <- c('A__B__Mike','A__Paul','Daniel','A__B__C__Martha','A__John','A__B__C__D__Laura')
```

I want a vector of only the names in the last position; I guess I could do it removing the first chunk using regular expressions, but say I want to use strsplit() to split by '__':

```
 x.list <- strsplit(x, '__')
```

How would I access the last subelement (the names) of each element in this list? I only know how to do it if I know the position:

```
 sapply(x.list, "[[", 1)
```

But how to access the last when the position is variable? Thanks!

In any case, what would be the fastest way to extract the names out of x in the first place? Anything faster than the strsplit approach?

Comment: Instead of `sapply`, you can use `mapply` to apply over multiple objects at once: `mapply(\`[[\`, x.list, lengths(x.list))`. I think the various options in akrun's answer are good if you actually care about speed, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`.  Either using `sub`

```
sub(".*__", "", x)
#[1] "Mike"   "Paul"   "Daniel" "Martha" "John"   "Laura"
```

---

or with `strsplit`, we get the last element with `tail`

```
sapply(strsplit(x, '__'), tail, 1)
#[1] "Mike"   "Paul"   "Daniel" "Martha" "John"   "Laura"
```

---

Or to find the position, we can use `gregexpr` and then extract using `substring`

```
substring(x, sapply(gregexpr("[^__]+", x), tail, 1))
#[1] "Mike"   "Paul"   "Daniel" "Martha" "John"   "Laura"
```

---

Or with `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(x, regex="[^__]+")
#[1] "Mike"   "Paul"   "Daniel" "Martha" "John"   "Laura"
```

Comment: Yes! tail is what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `word` function of `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
word(x,start = -1,sep = "\\_+")
```